# Hyperledger Fabric - MSPs of Small players using Infrastructure of Large players

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a doubt. 
Let us consider a scenario. A Large OEM and Few Large Vendors and Many Small Vendors are participating in a blockchain network. The small vendors may not be able to afford to set-up separate infrastructure / a dedicated Node to participate in the network. In that case,

- Will we be able to enable the OEM or any Large Vendors to
  provide access to the small vendors to participate in the blockchain
  network, via their own node (i.e. infrastructure as a service), for a
  small subscription fee?
- Will we be able to create
  private channels to those small vendors, providing the privacy from
  the large vendor whose infrastructure is been used?
- Will they be put as sub-organisations (logically in Membership Service Provider, not in real world acquisition or something like that) of the large vendor, like which we can commonly see in LDAP?

Answer (score 1):

If a small vendor is using infrastructure provided by a larger vendor, then unless they have the necessary permissions to allow them to generate certificates and configure peers, and the infrastructure provider does not have access to these certificates, they are implicitly trusting that vendor with their data. Since this removes one of the advantages of a blockchain solution, maybe it would be preferable for the small vendor to use their own cloud-hosted infrastructure?

This could be done with only a single VM for a small low-throughput implementation. VM templates could even be provided for popular cloud providers to make it easy for the smaller vendors to configure their peer.